# What are proper places to detect foreground/background delegates in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

## Backgound:

I am working in an iOS application. We have around 100 `ViewControllers` and all of them in our application are inherited from `BaseViewController` from the beginning. Currently while refactoring, I see many view controllers require to detect `willEnterForegroundNotification`[[1]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground) and `didEnterBackgroundNotification`[[2]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground)
 delegates to do some internal tasks. Almost **20~25** view controllers are setting their own notification observers to the delegates on their `viewDidLoad`. I was thinking to move this detection task to central `BaseViewController` for code clarity.

## My Proposed Solution:

My intended design is like below,

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    }

    func appMovedToBackground() {
        print("App moved to Background!")
    }

    func appMovedToForeground() {
        print("App moved to ForeGround!")
    }
}


class MyViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func appMovedToBackground() {
        print(“Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToBackground”)
    }

    override func appMovedToForeground() {
        print(“Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToForeground”)
    }
}
```

I see that if I move this detection into `BaseViewController` many tasks of custom observer handling are reduced from child view controllers. Child ViewControllers (i.e. `MyViewController` in example code) only need to use these two functions **`appMovedToBackground`** and **`appMovedToForeground`** when they require.

## Issues:

However, I am still concern about one thing. As I am moving the observer setting part into `BaseViewController`, thus all the `ViewControllers` (approx 100 of them in my project) will register the observer in their default `viewDidLoad` and many of them won’t even use them in reality. I am afraid this design might heavily costs app performance. Is my intended design acceptable when trading of between performance vs code clarity and maintainability in such situation? Is there any better design in my case?

---

## Reference:

<sup>[1] **willEnterForegroundNotification** - Posted when the app enters the background.</sup>

<sup>[2] **didEnterBackgroundNotification** - Posted shortly before an app leaves the background state on its way to becoming the active app.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notification is one to many communication. If you really don't this functionality. you can use the protocol delegate method. you can assign a delegate, only when you need it.

and to solve your problem, you can move your observer to didSet of delegate variable. So, only when you assign a delegate, that time only observers will be added. if you don't set it, it will not be added for that viewController.

```
@objc protocol AppActivityTracker{
    func appMovedToBackground()
    func appMovedToForeground()
}
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var activityDelegate : AppActivityTracker? {
        didSet{
            //MARK:-Observer will be added only when you assign delegate.
            let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
            notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(activityDelegate?.appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
            notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(activityDelegate?.appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}


class MyViewController: BaseViewController   {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //MARK:- Assign delegate only when you need observers
        activityDelegate = self
    }
}
 //MARK:- Assign delegate only when you need observers
extension MyViewController : AppActivityTracker{
    func appMovedToBackground() {
         print("Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToBackground")
     }

     func appMovedToForeground() {
         print("Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToForeground")
     }
}
```

**Discussion from comment:-**

**Adding observer on `viewWillAppear` and removing observer on `viewDidDisappear`**.

```
@objc protocol AppActivityTracker{
    func appMovedToBackground()
    func appMovedToForeground()
}
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var activityDelegate : AppActivityTracker? {
        didSet{
            if activityDelegate != nil{
                addOberservers()
            }
            else{
                removeOberservers()
            }
        }
    }
    func addOberservers(){
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(activityDelegate?.appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(activityDelegate?.appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
    func removeOberservers(){
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
}


class MyViewController: BaseViewController   {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
          //MARK:- Assign delegate only when you need observers
        self.activityDelegate = self
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        //MARK:- Removing observer on view will disappear.
        self.activityDelegate = nil
    }
}
 //MARK:- Assign delegate only when you need observers
extension MyViewController : AppActivityTracker{
    func appMovedToBackground() {
         print("Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToBackground")
     }

     func appMovedToForeground() {
         print("Do whatever need to do for current view controllers on appMovedToForeground")
     }
}
```

Comment: `Sazzad Hissain Khan` Is this solution solved your problem?

Comment: What if i need to register in viewWillAppear and deregister in viewDidDisappear? How do i deal it then?

Comment: you can create func for adding observer and removing observer in parent class. and call them from child VC view will appear and we will disappear.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Please check the updated answer for your requirement

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a protocol lets call it `BGFGObserver`.
Let each VC which needs to observe for foreground, background confirm to this protocol.
In base class check if `self` confirms to `BGFGObserver`, if yes then only register as observer. 
In `BGFGObserver` you will need to have the methods to handle background and foreground.

Comment: You mean in all cases of setting observers and calling them from `BaseViewController`, I need to check if the caller confronts to the `delegate` before calling? Elaborating your answer with example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in AppDelegate or create a separate class that is held in AppDelegate to specifically do this.